# HTML from database displays as plain text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Code First and I am introducing test data into the data base everytime the model changes.
The problem comes when I do the following:

```
 context.News.Add(new News
            {
                Id = 3,
                NewsTitle = "title",
                NewsImage = "thumb.jpg",
                NewsText = "text",
                Venue = @"<iframe width=""1000"" height=""350"" frameborder=""0"" scrolling=""no"" marginheight=""0"" marginwidth=""0"" src=""https://maps.google.ro/maps?hl=ro&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=h&amp;ll=46.778815,23.614479&amp;spn=0.002572,0.010718&amp;z=17&amp;output=embed""></iframe>"
             });
```

I have tried with \ instead of double quotes too...still nothing. The problem is that when I use the "Venue" on the page, it displays as plain text:

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">
     @News.Venue
</div>
```

What should I do to get it as html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
@Html.Raw(News.Venue)
```

This will output `News.Venue` in raw HTML, unencoded. See [HtmlHelper.Raw on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) for more information. You may of course want to be careful of the content in `.Venue`, if it comes from a third party, and sanitise it from scripts or unwanted content.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific [MvcHtmlString class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) that is designed to store strings that are HTML-encoded and should not be encoded again when rendering.

Comment: I feel *very* iffy about referencing System.Web.Mvc in my entity-project... =)